# Samsung Galaxy s3 still vibrating when getting notification, even though I'm on silent mode

Tags: notifications, vibration

I have Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300.

When I put it on silent mode, when I get a notification from Facebook, Facebook Messenger and GMail, or any other notification, it's still vibrating. This is very annoying when I'm in the classroom, for example.

Is there any option to completely disable vibration on silent mode?

Comment: In settings -> Sound, don't you have an options like "Vibrate" or "Silent Mode" ?

Comment: @Shywim I can totally turn off vibration, but I want to disable only in silent mode ..

Comment: i did both stips and they work perfectly really thank you so much you were helpful

Answer (score 2):

This is for Galaxy Nexus, but if you long press the power button, it should create a prompt that allows you to switch between Silent Mode, Vibrate Mode, and Sound Mode.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the S3 has similar options on its power-button dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put the device in silent mode using the volume hard keys. Presumably the designers thought it was more commonplace to set the device to vibrate only.

To make the S III completely silent, pull down the notification panel, tap the **Sound** shortcut at the top to switch it to **Vibrate**, then tap it again to switch it to **Mute**. (A third tap sets it back to **Sound*.)

If you've removed that shortcut from the notification panel, you can add it again. Open the **Settings** app, click **Display**, then **Notification panel**. There you can long-tap to pick up **Sound** from the **Available buttons** list, and drop it in **Notification panel**.

Comment: This is exuactly the issue: I'm on mute mode (as you said to do), but it's still vibrate.

Answer (score 0):

I just turned off the vibration intensity for notifications.

See:

> Settings > Sounds > Vibration Intensity > Notification

Comment: worked for me ;)